# Разбить список значений на отдельные строки

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Таблица 1]

Как преобразовать данные из первой таблицы во вторую? Сделать нужно через Pandas

[image: Таблица 2]

```
for i in range(len(robot_db['id'])):    
    buffer = [x for x in robot_db['id'][i]]    
    for j in range(len(robot_db['robot'][i])):
        robot_db['final'] = robot_db['id'][i] + '*' + robot_db['Name'][i]
        + '*' + robot_db['latitude'][i] + '*' + robot_db['longitude'][i]
        + '*' + buffer[j] + '/n'
```

Comment: Сколько можно говорить: данные в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде?

Comment: Как понять в воспроизводимом?) нужно в результате получить строки из столбца robot которые будет привязанны отдельно каждое значение к остальным столбцам в строке относящиеся к его значению

Comment: в воспроизводимом - это чтобы отвечающий мог скопировать  ваши данные и работать с ними. иными словами, данные должны быть в текстовом виде или в виде ссылки на текстовый файл или cvs.

Comment: И опишите словами алгоритм, по которому у вас из первой таблицы получается вторая.

Comment: Понял, завтра сделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На англоязычном сайте есть [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58523449/1328439) подобной задачи.

Идея - использовать метод `explode()`

```py
robodb = pd.DataFrame({'id': [2,2,4,4], 
                       'robot':['A,B,C','D,E,F','J,I,K','L,M,N']})
robodb['robot'] = robodb.robot.str.split(',')
robodb.explode('robot').reset_index(drop=True))
```

В результате из датафрейма

```
   id  robot
0   2  A,B,C
1   2  D,E,F
2   4  J,I,K
3   4  L,M,N
```

получается

```
   id robot
0   2     A
1   2     B
2   2     C
3   2     D
4   2     E
5   2     F
6   4     J
 ...
```

Comment: Да, `explode` должно работать для таких случаев

Comment: разобрался с explode все работает как нужно